# How to create number formations in JAVA

Tags: java, numbers

Can you help me for my assignment. I don't know how to execute this kind of outputs?

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

and

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7
8 9 
10
```

and lastly

```
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4   4 3 2 1
1 2 3       3 2 1
1 2     *     2 1
1     * * *     1
1 2     *     2 1
1 2 3       3 2 1
1 2 3 4   4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

Thank you! 
- 1st year programming student.

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework for you. Look at while loops and if statements. That's all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you could do something like

```
 "var i = 1"
 "var spaces = 1"
 "var counter = 1"
 "length = 1"
while(i < 11)
{
 for(spaces <= counter)
   {
    print i 
    i++
    spaces ++
   }
 print (pass line)
 spaces = 0
 counter ++ 

 }
```

this way you will get to print the var "i" until it gets to 11
and with the counter and the spaces var you will pass a line at 1,2,3.... numbers respectivily.
but since its your homework and you didnt specified in which language do you want the code i will let that to you. also dont ask us to do your code in the future.

Comment: ah, forgot to say. 
good luck with programming school. and this code will only help to the first one think about the next ones yourself, or you will never succed at programming

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me in my problem. God bless :)

Comment: no prob, and good luck